# Pass a system argument into the following function

Tags: python

Regardless of what I do with sys.argv[1:]; I cannot seem to get the following script to accept it. I've tried converting the sys.argv from a list to a single string and I still get an error returned when the detect() function is called. Any clues?

```
import cv2
import sys

def detect(path):
    img = cv2.imread(path)
    cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml")
    rects = cascade.detectMultiScale(img, 1.3, 4, cv2.cv.CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, (20,20))

    if len(rects) == 0:
        return [], img
    rects[:, 2:] += rects[:, :2]
    return rects, img

def box(rects, img):
    for x1, y1, x2, y2 in rects:
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (127, 255, 0), 2)
    cv2.imwrite('detected1.jpg', img);


file = sys.argv[1:]
#file = 'image.jpg'
print sys.argv[1:]
rects, img = detect(file)
box(rects, img)
```

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: Version 2.7; it's returning something from within numpy I believe...opencv is using it.

Comment: cv2.error: /home/lab/opencv-2.4.9/modules/core/src/array.cpp:2482: error: (-206) Unrecognized or unsupported array type in function cvGetMat

Answer (score 1):

`file` does not equal `'image.jpg'` because `sys.argv` is a *list* of arguments and doing `[1:]` simply creates a new list:

```
>>> argv = ['script_name.py', 'image.jpg']
>>> file = argv[1:]
>>> file
['image.jpg']
>>> type(file)
<class 'list'>
>>>
```

Instead of using slice notation to extract the filename, you should be indexing the `sys.argv` list:

```
>>> argv = ['script_name.py', 'image.jpg']
>>> file = argv[1]  # Notice there is no :
>>> file
'image.jpg'
>>> type(file)
<class 'str'>
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

`sys.argv` is a list of strings, not a single string. So `sys.argv[1:]` is also a list, not a string, which is probably why this is failing. Maybe you just meant `sys.argv[1]`?

Answer (score 1):

`sys.argv[1:]` is a list of every argument. So when it is passed to `detect` you try to load an image from a list, instead of a filename.

You either want to just take the first argument:

```
file = sys.argv[1]
```

Or to perform the operations for each argument:

```
for file in sys.argv[1:]:
    rects, img = detect(file)
    box(rects, img)
```

Comment: Isn't sys.argv[1] still a list?

Comment: No. It's the second element of the list, which is the first argument (because the first element is the script name).

Comment: It's still producing the same result when dropping the colon though. The for loop works fine though.

Comment: If I wanted to sys.argv out the part where it writes the image without the same error how would I do that?
Replacing 'detected1.jpg' in this part here:
cv2.imwrite('detected1.jpg', img);

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're asking.